# QTreeWidget sending signal doubleClicked

Tags: python, signals, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget structure like this:

```
root  
     |   
    groups
        |
        tables
```

I am trying to do something when there is a "doubleClick" but ONLY in the the childs called "tables".

The only good result that I have been able to get is:

```
self.ui.treeWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.treeWidgetItemAction)
```

The problem now is that ALL the elements in the QTreeWidget are responding to the "doubleClick". I do not want that, but I do not know how to reference only the children in the final branch of the tree.

Any help??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just make your `treeWidgetItemAction` method check whether the doubleCliked item is one that should react on doubleClicks, and only do what you want to do in that case.

To know where an item is a leaf, you could check it's `childCount` method. If it doesn't have any children, it's a leaf.

Comment: You are right. In that case, I'm not sure I understand what items should react on doubleclicks. Only leaves ?

Comment: Thanks Madjar, I will try to fix it!

Comment: Yes, just leaves must react to "doubleClick"

Comment: @user2919052 Then check their number of children, that's how you can tell whether it's a leaf.